# не получается поднять текст при помощи css

Tags: html, css

Вот код:

```css
.blue_bg {
  background: url('Fon.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.upp_quete {
  margin: 0em 0em 20em 0em;
}

.quete p {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.Utug {
  padding: 0em 0em 0em 45em;
}
```

```html
<section class="blue_bg">
  <div class="Utug">
    <a href="#"><img src="Utug.png" alt="Utug"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="upp_quete">
    <div class="quete">
      <p>утюг Braun TS 345</p>
      <p>Утюг с пароувлажнением для непревзойденного результата</p>
      <p>cглажения даже мелких деталей одежды.</p>
      <p>Глубоко проникающий пар разглаживает самые трудные участки ткани.</p>
      <p>Безупречный результат быстро и просто.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Не получается переместить текст чуть выше вместо этого увеличивается изображение вставленное в фон... Подскажите как это исправить?

Comment: Какой текст нужно поднять? Весь?

Comment: Да весь текст указанный в классе quete

Comment: куда поднять? Изображение должно быть справа от текста или выше него на всю ширину экрана? Обнуление `margin` для абзацев пробовали? Пишите, пожалуйста, более развернутые вопросы.

Comment: Смотрите, изображение должно находится с правой стороны,а текст с левой.
Обнуление margin не делал, можете подсказать как это делается?

Comment: и как это обнуление используется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```css
.blue_bg {
  background: url('Fon.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.upp_quete {
  margin: 0em 0em 20em 0em;
}

.quete p {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 1em;
  
  margin: 0;
  /*     ^^^ 
   *     Обнуляем отступы
   */
}

.img-link {
  
  float: right;
  /*     ^^^^^ 
   *     Выравниваем по правой стороне
   */
}
```

```html
<section class="blue_bg">
  <div class="upp_quete">
    <div class="quete">
    
      <!-- строчный элемент должен быть в том же блоке -->
      <a href="#" class="img-link"><img src="Utug.png" alt="Utug"></a>
      
      <p>утюг Braun TS 345</p>
      <p>Утюг с пароувлажнением для непревзойденного результата</p>
      <p>cглажения даже мелких деталей одежды.</p>
      <p>Глубоко проникающий пар разглаживает самые трудные участки ткани.</p>
      <p>Безупречный результат быстро и просто.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```